# Finding group delay of transfer function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, signal-processing, control-systems

I'm having trouble finding the group delay of a transfer function. I've seen a solved question on here about finding the group delay, but I want to understand why my method doesn't work.

Here is some sample code:

```
h = ButterworthFilterModel[3]
sss = h[I w][[1, 1]]
phase = Arg[sss]
groupDelay = -D[phase, w]
Table[groupDelay, {w, 0, 5, 0.1}]
```

The problem is that the group delay is giving complex numbers when I expect them to be real. The phase should be a real valued function, and if I test a few values, it indeed seems so. However, when I take the derivative, I start to get complex numbers again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
h = ButterworthFilterModel[3];
sss = h[I w][[1, 1]];
phase = ArcTan@@ComplexExpand@ReIm@sss;
groupDelay = -D[phase, w];
Table[groupDelay, {w, 0, 5, 0.1}] // Chop
```

> {2., 2.0102, 2.04307, 2.10467, 2.20218, 2.33846, 2.50245, 2.65754, 2.74073, 2.69171, 2.5, 2.21471, 1.90347, 1.61361, 1.36504, 1.16015, 0.993811, 0.859041, 0.749315, 0.659249, 0.584615, 0.522165, 0.469411, 0.424449, 0.38581, 0.352349, 0.323169, 0.297559, 0.274951, 0.254885, 0.236986, 0.220949, 0.20652, 0.193486, 0.181671, 0.170924, 0.161119, 0.152148, 0.143916, 0.136345, 0.129363, 0.122911, 0.116935, 0.11139, 0.106235, 0.101433, 0.0969522, 0.092765, 0.0888456, 0.0851716, 0.0817228}

Comment: Thanks, that seems to give the correct answer (other than I think there might possible be one too many minus signs). But other than that, do you know why this works but using Arg doesn't? Does this method just split up some of the steps in a way that Mathematica better understands?

Comment: I messed up a negative sign, which I have now fixed.

Comment: [`Arg`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arg.html) is not a differentiable function and [as documented](https://wolfram.com/xid/0bue8r-zvk3va) another way to get it in terms of differentiable functions is `phase=ComplexExpand[Arg[sss],TargetFunctions->{Re,Im}]`

Comment: Interesting, my local help documents (pressing F1 on Arg) don't mention anything about the complex numbers in the "Possible Issues" section. I have a recent version of Mathematica (12.0). I didn't know there are more details if you search for the function online. Thanks for showing this!

Comment: Do you see it by entering `ref/Arg#1547431236` in the Documentation Center?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. If type `ref/Arg#1547431236` in the address bar in the In-Mathematica documentation, I don't see the comments about Arg not working for complex numbers, but if I modify the url in the Mathematica-Website documentation (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arg#1547431236), I do get it.

Comment: I just checked, this example is only in 12.1 and not in 12.0. That's why you don't see it in 12.0. The online version has the latest 12.1 documentation.